Error: The requested DurationSeconds exceeds the MaxSessionDuration set for this role
I get this error when exeCuting my github actions workflow
I checked in the AWS console and the Maximum session duration is set to 1 hour for this role
Here is the steps configuration
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Configure AWS credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: us-east-2
      role-session-name: GithubActions
      role-duration-seconds: 3600
      role-skip-session-tagging: true

I don't understand why am getting that error
Please I'd appreciate any help
Thanks
When I initially got the error I added role-duration-seconds: 3600
I was  able to assume the role via the aws cli
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx— role-session-name test-session --external-id false --duration-seconds 3600
